# nvd3 xAxis ticks scale not linear

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

So I was able to create a graph with evenly spaced ticks so that the xAxis would have every hour of the last day. I can do the same with days, so that the xAxis would havve every day of the last week. As soon as I try to construct one graph with both the last week by day and the last day by hour, the graph bugs out. I assume it's because I have different time scales but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include a CodePen/Plunkr example showing the issue and a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: @jeznag I'm sorry, I already fixed it with time.format.multi.

Comment: Perhaps you could post an answer to your own question then to help other people